# how to install python third modules into virtualenv?

Tags: software-installation, python-2.7, parallels, virtualenv, numpy

I installed a virtual environment for python. I succeeded to install numpy and scipy but not parallel python. How can I install or build third modules into the virtualenv?

I tried to `sudo apt-get python-pp` , it worked and installed the last version but I can't call the module import pp after launching the virtualenv

Previously done to install python + last scipy stack in a terminal:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential gfortran libblas3gf libblas-doc libblas-dev  liblapack3gf liblapack-doc liblapack-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install python-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install python-pp
>
> sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv

mkdir + cd into appropriate dedicated folder

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages virtualenv
```

> source ./virtualenv/bin/activate
>
> pip install numpy scipy

How to install and build python third modules into the virtualenv? Thanks for your incoming help and explanations.

**Answer:**
after `pip install numpy scipy` , go into `./virtualenv/bin/` and there apply Nicholas commands:

```
wget http://www.parallelpython.com/downloads/pp/pp-1.6.4.zip
unzip -e pp-1.6.4.zip
cd pp-1.6.4
python setup.py install
```

to test,

```
python
import pp
```

Thanks to Nicholas I

Comment: this question should also help people/students/scientifics that need to install latest version of scipy stack and python ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. `wget http://www.parallelpython.com/downloads/pp/pp-1.6.4.zip`
2. `unzip -e pp-1.6.4.zip`
3. `cd pp-1.6.4`
4. `python setup.py install`

Comment: Could you expand on your answer and state what these commands achieve?

Comment: Ok, it works. To complete your answer, I installed pp from virtualenv. I suppose that such install forces the process to happen into the virtualenv … or may be it's a known issue from apt-get install python-pp? I agree with M.Lindman, you are quite sparse in "explanations" ^^ Thanks anyway!